# Bounding an integral involving tail probabilities

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, triangle-inequality, empirical-processes

I am currently reading through Van der Vaart and Wellner's book on empirical process theory. In chapter 2.9, they define the quantity
$$||\xi||_{2,1} \equiv \int_0^\infty \sqrt{P(|\xi| > x)}\,\mathrm dx$$
They then claim in their problem 2.9.2 that while this is not a norm in the sense of not satisfying the triangle inequality, we nonetheless have the bound
$$||\xi+\eta||_{2,1}^2 \leq 4||\xi||_{2,1}^2 + 4||\eta||_{2,1}^2$$
which is sufficient for the purposes of the results shown in the chapter. I am at a loss for how to tackle this problem. I have tried a few approaches, each of which seems to lead to a dead end. Directly bounding $P(|\xi + \eta| > x)$ in terms of useful properties appears to be difficult, largely owing to the fact that it is hard to get a handle on the cases where $|\xi| < x, |\eta| < x$, but their sum is $> x$. I also had an idea that because the square root function monotonically maps $[0,1]$ to itself, we could associate to each random variable $\xi$ a $\xi'$ that satisfies $P(|\xi'| > x)^2 - P(|\xi| > x)$, which would imply that $||\xi||_{2,1} = ||\xi||_1$, but this does not appear to be of much help either, as it is unclear how $\xi' + \eta'$ defined this way would relate to $(\xi + \eta)'$. I would appreciate any hints about how to proceed.

Comment: Are $\xi$ and$\eta$ Rademacher RVs?

Comment: Not necessarily. The result should be general.

Comment: I can prove it with 8 instead 4. If it works for you, let me know and I'll write it down.

Comment: Yeah that works too. It only really matters that it’s a finite number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand I can bound the probability in $\|\xi+\eta\|_{2,1}$ as:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}(|\xi+\eta|>x)&\leq\mathbf{P}(|\xi|+|\eta|>x)\\
&\leq\mathbf{P}(\{|\xi|>x/2\}\cup\{|\eta|>x/2\})\\
&\leq\mathbf{P}(|\xi|>x/2)+\mathbf{P}(|\eta|>x/2)
\end{align}
Then the pseudo-norm can be bounded as:
\begin{align}
\|\xi+\eta\|_{2,1}&=\int_0^\infty\sqrt{\mathbf{P}(|\xi+\eta|>x)}dx\\
&\leq\int_0^\infty\sqrt{\mathbf{P}(|\xi|>x/2)+\mathbf{P}(|\eta|>x/2)}dx\\
&\leq
\int_0^\infty\sqrt{\mathbf{P}(|\xi|>x/2)}dx+\int_0^\infty\sqrt{\mathbf{P}(|\eta|>x/2)}dx\\
&=2\left[\int_0^\infty\sqrt{\mathbf{P}(|\xi|>t)}dt+\int_0^\infty\sqrt{\mathbf{P}(|\eta|>t)}dt\right]\\
&=2\left(\|\xi\|_{2,1}+\|\eta\|_{2,1}\right)
\end{align}
On the other hand, I can use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality $|a|+|b|\leq\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ as
\begin{align}
\|\xi+\eta\|_{2,1}^2&\leq4\left(\|\xi\|_{2,1}+\|\eta\|_{2,1}\right)^2\\
&\leq8(\|\xi\|_{2,1}^2+\|\eta\|_{2,1}^2)
\end{align}
Unfortunally I can't bound with 4 instead 8.

Comment: Where is the bound $P(|\xi| + |\eta| > x) \leq P(\{|\xi| > x/2\} \cup \{|\eta| > x/2\})$ coming from?

Comment: Because $\{|\xi|+|\eta|>x\}\subset\{|\xi|>x/2\}\cup\{|\eta|>x/2\}$. Think about it for the absurd: if $|\xi|\leq x/2$ and $|\eta|\leq x/2$ it is impossible than $|\xi|+|\eta|>x$.

Comment: Ahh, right...I think I was getting stuck because I kept treating "$\cup$" as if it behaved like "$\cap$"...

Comment: Actually, couldn't you get the constant of 4 by instead saying $P(|\xi| + |\eta| > x) \leq P(|\xi| > \lambda x) + P(|\eta| > (1-\lambda) x)$ and optimizing over the choice of $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes, but each norm will be multiplied by a different value.